# Errors at image after set my web on public

Tags: php, html, css

I got errors after setup my website on public and when I finished I tried to upload the image and get errors. Is this because my website doesn't use database?

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/Capture.PNG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd5/873/2077873/public_html/upload.php on line 28
>   Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/storage/ssd5/873/2077873/tmp/phpuRC82y' to 'uploads/Capture.PNG' in /storage/ssd5/873/2077873/public_html/upload.php on line 28

My code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>image sharer</title>
  <style>
     footer {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%;
     }
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <h1><font color="green">@img</font><font color="blue">serv</font></h1>
   <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      image selector :<input type="file" name="image"><br/><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
   </form>

   <?php
      if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
      $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
      $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
      $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
      $image_tmp_name= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      @$desc = $_POST['desc'];
      move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name,"uploads/$image_name");
      echo "<img src='uploads/$image_name' width='400' height='250'><br>";
      echo "your image : ";
      }
  ?>

   <footer>
      <a href="tos.html" class="bottomLinks">tos</a> - <a href="faq.html" class="bottomLinks">faq</a> - <a href="contact.html" class="bottomLinks">contact us</a> 
      <span id="footerRight" class="copyright footerFont"><strong>@imgserv v1.1 </strong>
      </span>
    </div>
  </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include the error?

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(uploads/Capture.PNG): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd5/873/2077873/public_html/upload.php on line 28

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/storage/ssd5/873/2077873/tmp/phpuRC82y' to 'uploads/Capture.PNG' in /storage/ssd5/873/2077873/public_html/upload.php on line 28

Comment: uploads directory is not exist or you are giving the wrong path to uploads folder.

Comment: I updated your question for you - see how I did it

Comment: everything is ok and work i test that before i make it public                                 even every image is uploaded is stored in uploads folder

Comment: no just upload it and when i use the domain i get the above errors

Comment: It's a permissions issue, you need to enable write access for Apache via chmod and chown.

Comment: is says 'no such directory'. Does the directory ./uploads exsist? (writing permisssions should also be granted, but when missing that should be an other error-message,

Comment: any guide how to enable it

Answer (score 0):

The problems are not caused by the fact your website does not use a database.

The error message does point out that the elected upload directory cannot be found. Before attempting to write to that directory it would be better to test that it exists and if it does not create the necessary file structure. The function `createdir` below will recusively create the folder structure.

The upload handling code referenced a non-existant form field `desc` so you would likely have found an issue with that also.

```
<?php

    function createdir( $path=null, $perm=0644 ) {
        if( !file_exists( $path ) ) {
            createdir( dirname( $path ) );
            mkdir( $path, $perm, true );
            clearstatcache();
        }
    }

    $uploadstatus = false;

    if( isset( $_POST['upload'], $_FILES['image'] ) ){
        $obj=(object)$_FILES['image'];

        $name=$obj->name;
        $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
        $size=$obj->size;
        $error=$obj->error;
        $type=$obj->type;


        if( $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK && is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){
            $target_directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads';
            $target_file = $target_directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name;

            if( !file_exists( $target_directory ) ){
                createdir( $target_directory );
            }

            $uploadstatus = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $target_file );
        }
    }

?>


<html>
   <head>
      <title>image sharer</title>
      <style>
         footer {
         font-family: sans-serif;
         position:absolute;
         bottom:0;
         width:100%;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1><font color="green">@img</font><font color="blue">serv</font></h1>
      <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <label>Image selector :<input type="file" name="image"></label><br/>
         <label>Description: <input type='text' name='desc' /></label><br/>
         <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
         <?php

            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && $uploadstatus==true ){
                echo "
                <img src='/uploads/{$name}' width='400' height='250' />
                <br />
                Your image : {$name} - {$_POST['desc']}";
            }

         ?>
      </form>
      <footer>
         <a href="tos.html" class="bottomLinks">tos</a> - 
         <a href="faq.html" class="bottomLinks">faq</a> - 
         <a href="contact.html" class="bottomLinks">contact us</a> 
         <span id="footerRight" class="copyright footerFont"><strong>@imgserv v1.1 </strong></span>
         </div>
      </footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

uploads folder is missing in your directory..please create uploads directory in your website folder